# Javascript Array Table Pagination

Tags: javascript, arrays, pagination

I want to achieve pagination (5 records per page) for this simple JavaScript array table having pagination controls.

So far I created a table with data:

```
 jsfiddle.net/QwBsa/13/
```

Can anyone route me to any demo or reference ?

Comment: If anybody looks at your question next year, the code will be gone.

Comment: Have you thought of using a JavaScript framework for this? I think SlickGrid (https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) is ideal for that task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use jQuery.dataTables...which gives the pagination as well as sorting options
include this

```
   <link href="css/demo_page.css" rel="stylesheet" id="stylesheet"/>
      <link href="css/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <script  src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

and create table as like yours in javascript and declare class name as "abc"

```
               var table = document.createElement('table');
               table.setAttribute("class","abc");
              var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
```

and call jquery display length will be the number of data to be displayed,

jQuery call:

```
        $('#abc').dataTable({

        "iDisplayLength": 5,

           });
```

for reference use see website

www.datatables.net

Comment: could you please give me any link to dataTables simple demonstration ?